# What is it that parses the LSB information in init scripts?

Tags: init-script, init.d, lsb

At the top of files in `/etc/init.d` are comments like the following.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        ntp
# Required-Start:  $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:   $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:    1
# Short-Description: Start NTP daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

What is the program that parses those comments? I'm interested in seeing how it does it. Is it a script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [LSB](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html) info is parsed by `insserv` on older Ubuntu and Debian systems, and by [chkconfig](https://github.com/kergoth/chkconfig) on older Redhat and Fedora systems, and is now parsed by 
`/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-sysv-generator` on systems using systemd.

All of these are coded in C. The pre-systemd `chkconfig` sources in the above link are probably a good starting point.